# Key Repetition in SFML 2.0

Tags: c++, events, keyboard, sfml

Is there a way to receive if a key has just been pressed (not held) in SFML, or a way to mimic such an effect?

I poll my event here,

```
while (window.pollEvent(event));
```

And then later in the loop, out of scope but with the same event, I read:

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
{
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up)
    {
        decision--;
        if (decision < 0)
        decision = CHARACTER_MAX - 1;
    }
}
```

This makes `decision` decrement continuously when the up arrow is held down. Using `sf::event`s, can I read the first time it is pressed and not when it is held down?

Also, if its not possible or you're not familiar with sfml, what would be the best way to mimic such with little or no globalized variables? (such as `is_already_held`), e.g. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30826/action-button-only-true-once-per-press

I realize that such may be the only way (declaring a variable in a wider scope) but I would prefer not to, because I exit the scope continuously and try to steer clear from global variables as often as possible.

Comment: `while (window.pollEvent(event));` notice the `;` : you only got the last event after doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable key repetition with `sf::Window::setKeyRepeatEnabled`:

```
window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
```

Call it once (that's enough) after creating your window.

The documentation is [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php#aef9f2b14c10ecba8a8df95dd51c5bb73).

---

If, for any reason, you don't want to use this function, you can have a table of boolean to store the state of each key. Here is a pseudo code that shows how to keep the table up-to-date and integrates your 'decision' code.

```
// Init the table of state. true means down, false means up.
std::array<bool, sf::Keyboard::KeyCount> keyState;
keyState.fill(true);

// :
// :

// In the event loop:
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
{
    // If the key is UP and was not previously pressed:
    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up && !keyState[event.key.code])
    {
        decision--;
        if (decision < 0)
            decision = CHARACTER_MAX - 1;
    }

    // Here comes the rest of your code and at the end of the if-body:

    // Update state of current key:
    keyState[event.key.code] = true;
}
else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased)
{
    // Update state of current key:
    keyState[event.key.code] = false;
}
```

---

A third alternative is to use a third-party library such as **Thor**. It's still under development so you can expect some changes from the author. And [here](http://www.bromeon.ch/libraries/thor/v2.0/tutorial-actions.html) you'll find a tutorial on *Action* – that is, exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `sf::Event::KeyReleased` in lieu of the `sf::Event::KeyPressed` event, which will continue to run as long as a key is 'held', which your computer triggers considerably faster than the duration of a 'single' tap by a person.

If I run:

```
while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
   switch (event.type) {
     case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
       if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Enter) {
         std::cout << "Enter key pressed!" << std::endl;
       }
     break;
   default:
     break;
   }
}
```

I'll get:

```
Enter key pressed!
Enter key pressed!
Enter key pressed!
Enter key pressed!
... etc
```

any number of times (14, 23, 9, 31, etc.) based on the amount of time my finger held down the return key.

If I run:

```
while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
      if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Enter) {
        std::cout << "Enter key pressed!" << std::endl;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

I'll get:

```
Enter key pressed!
```

Only once, based on the single release of the return key. :)

There are definitely times when you want to use a `sf::Event::KeyPressed` event, such as holding the "zoom" button for a gun with a scope that only zooms while the key is down, or holding "Ctl" for "Ctl+alt+key" key combinations in a file editor, etc.

Comment: Note: the reason I prefer this to `setKeyRepeatEnabled()` or any 'key down' event is that it's just plain illogical to decide key down almost always. If you NEED a single tap to trigger an event vs. holding the key down, you wouldn't be holding the key down in the first place. This method is clean and still gives you access full use of 'key held' events when you wouldn't be using it in MOST cases if you weren't simply tapping keys.

Comment: There are some legitimate use cases in which one might want to have both. For example, if holding a key activates one behavior, while quickly pressing it and releasing repeatedly activates some other behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeated firing of the event when the key is down, you can use `sf::Event::KeyReleased` instead of `sf::Event::KeyPressed`. I'm assuming that's your goal.

If not, you'll have to store the button state. A class is the logical answer because it combines state with behavior.